# Trouble calling runbook when name is a variable

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Facing some unexpected behavior in Azure Automation that I just can't figure out.
I have a runbook called "Test2" with just 1 line in it, so I can see if it runs: `Write-Output "this works"`
I have another runbook called Test1. I want to call Test2 from Test1.

This code works fine. It runs Test2 twice:

```
$test = 'Test2'
& .\Test2.ps1
& .\"$test".ps1
```

However, THIS code fails to run Test2:

```
$test = 'Test2'
#& .\Test2.ps1
& .\"$test".ps1
```

Only change is commenting out the first call. So if I call the runbook just using its name, I can subsequently call it with the variable. But if I don't, I can't.

The error message confirms that it evaluates the variable, but for some reason it just can't find the runbook? Any assistance would be appreciated.
The error: `& : The term '.\Test2.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, When I execute the script without commenting the
`& .\test2.ps1`, it worked as expected.

```
$test = 'test2'
& .\test2.ps1
& .\"$test".ps1
write-output "call success"
```

*Output:*

[image]

Once its done, I tried running the same script as you (commented
`& .\test2.ps1`) and the call from `test` to `test2` runbook was successful as shown below.

[image]

[image]

Try checking the test2 file directory path once and re run the script.

If still the issue persists, as a workaround you can use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.4) command to take the call expression instead of substituting it in the variable.

```
$test = 'test2'
#& .\test2.ps1
Invoke-Expression "& .\$test.ps1"
write-output "call success"
```

*Output:*

[image]